# How to delete duplicate rows in merge replication

Tags: sql-server, replication, delete, merge-replication

Somehow two rows in a table that is party to merge replication are identical, including their `rowguid`. I have no idea how this happened, it is only with two rows in my entire database (which is used in production).

No matter how I try to delete them, I get the following error:

> Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Procedure MSmerge_del_12B5E838BB91458D81AD66DD7EB5ABDC, Line 46
>   Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.MSmerge_tombstone' with unique index 'uc1MSmerge_tombstone'. The duplicate key value is (7094001, df2e61b2-3d8e-e511-84bb-00155d00c1da).
>   The statement has been terminated.

This is somewhat expected, but I have no idea how to get around it. I'd very much like to avoid dropping anything big (i.e. replication, tables, etc.). This is an isolated case and I don't expect it to happen again so I don't mind doing a manual work-around.

Can anyone provide some insight into this?

Thanks!

Comment: By anychance you restored the database with `KEEP_REPLICATION` ? You rarely hit a dupe in `dbo.MSmerge_tombstone` unless a database is restored.

Comment: @Kin Yes, the subscriber is a restore of the publisher that may have had `KEEP_REPLICATION` enabled. I will keep that in mind for future restores, if necessary. Is there a way to correct this now though?

Comment: can you try to drop and recreate the index `uc1MSmerge_tombstone` to see if it fixes the problem ?

Comment: That worked! Awesome, thanks a lot! If you put that as an answer I'll mark it as correct. I scripted the index first (so I wouldn't have to write it out), then dropped it, deleted the row through T-SQL (can't do it through the Edit pane), then re-created the index.

Comment: Glad that it helped. I have posted as answer to get this out of queue of unanswered questions !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The duplicate rows in the MSmerge_tombstone occurs when you restore the database with `KEEP_REPLICATION` bit.

Its a good practice to configure replication from scratch since you never know that you run into some unknown issue just like you did.

As confirmed by OP - drop the index `uc1MSmerge_tombstone`, delete the offending row and   recreating the index fixes the problem.

Remember that you have to be caution when fiddling with `MSmerge*` tables.